# c++ Error when passing class object into class function from main?

Tags: c++, class, object

I am using a switch statement based off user's input to decide which function to call.
I then want to pass a class object to a class function in which the code will be that fills in the details of that class object.
Here are segments of my code:

```
//main.cpp
void myswitch(int input)
{
    switch (input)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            ElectricityBill eBill;
            ElectricityBill::eBillData(eBill);
            break;
        }
//----------------------------------------------
//bill.h
class ElectricityBill: public Bill
{
    public:
        void eBillData(ElectricityBill eBill);
};
//----------------------------------------------
//bill.cpp
void ElectricityBill::eBillData(ElectricityBill eBill)
{
    //get data
}
```

The error I am getting is:
error: cannot call member function 'void ElectricityBill::eBillData(ElectricityBill)' without object

Help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking a **member function**, so the object on which the function is going to be invoked will be passed implicitly to the `eBillData()` function if you just do:

```
ElectricityBill eBill;
eBill.eBillData();
```

Which is perhaps what you actually meant to do. In that case, `eBillData` should take no *explicit* argument (a pointer to `eBill` will be passed *implicitly*), and it will access all the necessary information about the object it is invoked on through the implicit `this` pointer:

```
#include <string>

class ElectricityBill: public Bill
{
    public:
        void eBillData();
    private:
        std::string something;
};
```

Now the definition of `eBillData()` should of course reflect the declaration above. Notice, that in a member function you can access data members of the object the function is being invoked on through the implicit `this` pointer, or (more commonly) but just using their name without the `this->` indirection. For instance:

```
#include <iostream>

void ElectricityBill::eBillData()
{
     // The following two statements are equivalent...
     std::cout << something;
     std::cout << this->something;
}
```